# disable GPS signal during location update

Tags: android

I am making location tracker application in android so I call a function
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
30000,
0,
listener);

So in this example i set 5minute interval.
Now my question is why GPS signal is constantly activate, though my interval time is 5minute..

Can't is deactivate till 5 minute and after 5 minute can't it automatically activate??
I thing device require more battery power though it constant active...
What I have to do to deactivate GPS for particular interval defined in function.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't but you can always run a service that asks for a single shot fix every five minutes.

For e/g use `requestSingleUpdate (String provider, PendingIntent intent)`

To broadcast an intent when a single shot fix is obtained.

Comment: Thanks for giving me reply, but I can not get your answer.. Please would you give me some source code

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with my app. I used a timer initialized on startup:

serviceHandler = new Handler();
serviceHandler.postDelayed( new RunTask(),1000L );

This runs locupdate and adds one to counter every second.

```
 class RunTask implements Runnable {
      public void run() {
        ++counter;
        locupdate(0,0);
        serviceHandler.postDelayed( this, 1000L );
      }
    }
```

this is the locupdate function used above. Note, mlocManager is defined globaly as a LocationManager.

```
public void locupdate(int minTime, float minDistance) {
    mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    if (mlocListener != null && mlocManager != null) {
        mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
    }
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                minTime, minDistance, mlocListener);
}
```

One last thing. At the end of the onLocationChanged method in LocationListener I remove updates after 5 locations fixes:

mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);

This is similar to requestSingleUpdate() but i find it more flexible. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh and one last thing. To prevent running two instances of your LocationListener, I defined a global variable that is set to true before locupdate() and set to false at the end of onLocationChanged. Before running locupdate you should make sure that variable is false. You also might want to check that an instance of the timer isn't already running on startup. If a user hits the back button and then reopens your app, onCreate is called a second time...

Answer (score 0):

Basically this function takes time interval as follows,

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, listener);

the meaning over here is that give me GPS update if you found within the given time with no

other priority tasks.

so this is you method

public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)

& these are the parameters, please read it carefully you can understand it

Parameters
minTime = the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.

minDistance = the minimum distance interval for notifications, in meters criteria contains parameters for the location manager to choose the appropriate provider and parameters to compute the location

intent = a {#link PendingIntent} to be sent for each location update

That is all about

Best Regards,
~Anup

Comment: Thnak's for give me reply, but I don't know how to give PendingIntent parameter..please will you give me some example link

Comment: are this is different flavours of requestLocationUpdates() please go through the following link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Comment: you will definitely get this issue fixed dont forget to mark it as  an answer